# undefined local variable or method `encrypted_password'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twitter, omniauth, ruby-2.0

I'm using devise and omniauth to allow users to access my site via twitter, sign up works fine, but when i try to login (with the user i just signed up with) i keep getting the following error:

"undefined local variable or method `encrypted_password' for #"

the thing is that my user model does not make use of `encrypted_password' anywhere.
Im using MongoDB and Mongoid.
Full trace:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-fe7f43430580/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:321:in `method_missing'
devise (3.0.0.rc) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:118:in `authenticatable_salt'
devise (3.0.0.rc) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:204:in `serialize_into_session'
devise (3.0.0.rc) lib/devise.rb:432:in `block (2 levels) in configure_warden!'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:27:in `store'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:175:in `set_user'
devise (3.0.0.rc) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:135:in `sign_in'
devise (3.0.0.rc) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:255:in `sign_in_and_redirect'
app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:7:in `all'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `_run__1123313306__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:654:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:401:in `call_app!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:363:in `callback_phase'
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:58:in `callback_phase'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `callback_call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:182:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-fe7f43430580/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `block in call'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-fe7f43430580/lib/mongoid/unit_of_work.rb:39:in `unit_of_work'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-fe7f43430580/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run__1368160554__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Devise use it. Did you run the migrations?

Comment: Im using MongoDB and Mongoid.

Answer (score 4):

SInce you are using mongoid ORM, you need to explicitly define fields in your model. I gave you the list of fields with the comment on top that specifies devise module that goes with it. You need to copy the fields according to what devise modules you are using:

```
  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              :type => String, :default => ""
  field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :default => ""

  ## Password Expirable
  field :password_changed_at, :type => Time

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   :type => String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, :type => Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, :type => Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      :type => Integer, :default => 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, :type => Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    :type => Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, :type => String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    :type => String

  ## Encryptable
  field :password_salt, :type => String

  ## Confirmable
  field :confirmation_token,   :type => String
  field :confirmed_at,         :type => Time
  field :confirmation_sent_at, :type => Time
  field :unconfirmed_email,    :type => String # Only if using reconfirmable
  field :deactivated,          :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :status,               :type => String, :default => Status::PENDING

  ## Lockable
  field :failed_attempts, :type => Integer, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  field :unlock_token,    :type => String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  field :locked_at,       :type => Time

  ## Token authenticatable
  field :authentication_token, :type => String

  ## Invitable
  field :invitation_token, :type => String
  field :invitation_sent_at, :type => Time
  field :invitation_accepted_at, :type => Time
  field :invitation_limit, :type => Integer, :default => 0
  field :invited_by_id, :type => String
  field :invited_by_type, :type => String
```

Comment: Im using omniauth and devise together. Devise for normal logging in and omniauth so that i can have 3rd party logins (twitter, facebook etc)

Comment: you need to add database_authenticatable migration then. it adds encrypted password to the DB. `t.database_authenticatable :null => false`

Comment: Im using MongoDB and Mongoid

Comment: I updated answer according to the info you gave me. I didnt see the MongoDB part in your question. sorry

Comment: i'm having the same issue with MongoDB @Mulaiko did you figured out?

Comment: @comonitos do you have `encrypted_password` field defined?

Comment: you have a different problem then. you should start new question and post your error log